# Turn-Based Game - Matches

Tags: center, game-center

I'm trying to do a turn-based game with Game Center.

My question is, can i limit the number of matches being played or created?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. One solution would be storing the number of currently games being play into database. and checking whether it exceeds the max limit of determined or not. 
I just finished developing my chess game -.-

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in limit to the number of simultaneous matches (currently 30).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know locally how many games the app is in (which is easy to find out by calling `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler`).

Then, is beyond your max number of games,  reject all invitations from `handleInviteFromGameCenter` and disable your UI for creating new games and do not create match requests.